# ASP.net code return open session errors

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, mysql-connector

this look like a simple issue but been need some help with this. When I am trying to run the following code I just get the error below. I did make sure the connection was opened and also made sure proper mySQL connection coding structure was followed. I'm just lost at this point.

```
 <%@ import namespace="System.Data" %> 
    <%@ import namespace="MySql.data.MySqlclient" %> 
    <%@ import namespace="MySql.data.MySqlclient.MySqlConnection" %> 

    <html>

      <head>
        <title>Get Data from a Database using ADO</title>
        <Script runat="server"> 
            Sub page_load()
                Dim username As String = Convert.ToString(User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\") + 1))
                Dim dbconn As MySqlConnection
                Dim dbCMD As MySqlCommand
                Dim mySqlCommand As MySqlCommand
                Dim counter As Integer
                Dim isInGroup As Boolean
                Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_staff WHERE username = @username AND 'group_id' = '1001'"

                dbconn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=imc_directory_tool;user=Directory_Admin;port=3306;password=IMCisgreat2014;")
                dbconn.Open()

                dbCMD = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, dbconn)
                mySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL)
                mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
                counter = mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
                If isInGroup = counter > 0 Then
                    Response.Redirect("http://www.w3schools.com")
                Else
                    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.ca")
                End If


                dbconn.Close()
            End Sub
        </Script>  

      </head>

      <body>
    Main page ...
      </body>

    </html>
```

Error:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open.


Line 23:             mySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL)
Line 24:             mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
Line 25:             counter = mySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
Line 26:             If isInGroup = counter > 0 Then
Line 27:                 Response.Redirect("http://www.w3schools.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving your "mySqlCommand" variable a connection. You should change line 23 to:

```
mySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, dbConn)
```

Also, your variable "dbCMD" is not being used.

You could also do:

```
set mySqlCommand = dbConn.CreateCommand()
```

If you get in the habit of doing it this way, you don't have to worry about assigning a connection to your command object.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me an example of how I should write this, im not quite sure I follow. Sorry im quite new at this but really appreciate the help.

Comment: Nevermind I re-read you answer it it worked. THank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Here is an example: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection~CreateCommand.html

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing this command 
(with connection)

```
            dbCMD = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, dbconn)
```

But executing this command 
(without connection)

```
            mySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(strSQL)
```

That's why the error produced.  Change your command for the execution.

My suggestion is go with DAL for contacting DB not using in your UI layer.

Comment: Would you be able to provide me an example of how I should write this, im not quite sure I follow. Sorry im quite new at this but really appreciate the help.